# Polynomial MULTIPLE Regression. Till which polynomial degree shall I try?

Tags: max, regression

I have around 50 dependent quantities (regressor variables).

I want to find the best relation between the response variable data and regressor variable data.

I tried multiple linear regression with 3 combinations but could not get correlation coefficient between original and predicted y variable greater than 0.5.

Hence, i am trying polynomial fit.

Starting from simple Quadratic Equation.

y = a.x1^2 + b.x2 + c

y, x1,x2,x3 ......... x50 is a matrix of 100 X 1 order.

Please help.

Can anyone suggest till how many polynomial degree shall I go to find best correlation value between original and predicted y variable ?

Which model is statistically better linear or polynomial ?

Secondly, How can I code this problem using matlab ?  Which matlab function can I use for this purpose ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A relationship between y and different x variables